# SharePoint 2013 app connected to PostgreSQL

Tags: 2013, list, sharepoint-foundation, database-connection, visual-studio-2013

I want to create an app for SharePoint 2013 (Foundation so far, soon to be paid version). I would love to include SP lists filled with data from sql query to PostgreSQL. Sounds easy, right?

I am unable to find a tutorial or code sample on how to achieve this. Is it possible? If not, why?

If it matters, I use VS 2013.

Answer (score 1):

I would set up a [Business Data Connectivity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163782%28v=office.15%29.aspx) model to consume data from PostgreSQL and expose it in the form of an external list.

There are plenty of tutorials on the internet on how to go about it, for example:
http://raquelalineblog.wordpress.com/2013/05/19/sharepoint-2013-bcs-in-visual-studio-2012/

Comment: Almost. I can't use your tutorial because I'm creating an app, not an empty sharepoint solution. Here are some more links: [link1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0ce75eaa-46ee-499b-9c62-44dc13ee8c7f/bcs-and-sharepoint-apps), [link2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163308.aspx)